# patch failed after pulling. Changes got lost

Tags: python, git, version-control, pycharm

I write code in python using pycharm. I usually use pycharm gui to perform git commands. Recently I pushed the "update project" button and something went wrong. While updating, after a while I received a message which said: patch failed. I tried to abort patch and rollback but I received the following message: "rollback failed, try using local history dialog for 'my project' and perform revert manually". Now I lost a lot of my changes. Files that I created seem to have disappeared, and so have some of the files that I moved. I also lost some changes in the files that I didn't create or move. Going to local history I can see the previous state of my code, but it's hard to go through it manually since I did have a lot of changes to keep track of.
Is there a way to revert everything to the state it was before I did this update?
Please help!

Comment: I recommend you hop into the terminal and run `git reflog`, then look through your history to try and find the commit that contains the changes you want. When you find it, run `git check <commit-hash>`. You should be able to do what you need from there.

Comment: What's the **update type** and **clean working tree before update** options did you select when you clicked update project button? And what's the output of `git status` command?